# add multiple behavior to viewingplatform java3d

Tags: java, java-3d

can anybody tell me how to attach more than one behavior to the viewingplatform?

```
OrbitBehavior orb = new OrbitBehavior(canvas3d, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL) ;
orb.setSchedulingBounds(boundingSphere);
viewingPlatform.setViewPlatformBehavior(orb);
```

lets say i want to move the camera in other ways. how do i add another behavior to viewingPlatform and keeping OrbitalBehavior at the same time.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

Java3D restricts you to a single ViewPlatformBehavior.

The best workaround is to write your own ViewPlatformBehavior that incorporates all the functionality you want, delegating to others as appropriate.